# How to format JSON in NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am starting with an NSArray and I'd like to convert the contents in the array with a JSON format.

Here is the content of the NSArray:

```
(
        {
        "men_clothing" =         {
            Tops = Activewear;
        };
    }
)
```

Here is the code I tried:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:userObject[@"userInterests"] options:0 error:nil];


    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:nil];


    NSLog(@"jSON%@",json);
```

I'd like to end up in JSON format within the NSArray.

Something like this is what I expect to see:

```
{
"men_clothing":          {
   "Tops":"Activewear"}
}
```

Comment: It is already in JSON format. Do you want to store it in array ?

Comment: in my database its in JSON format but when i retrieve it comes back like that.

Comment: very low quality question. @Farhan please, post some code, what object are you exactly logging. I think you need to google `NSJSONSerialization`

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov sorry about that, just updated with code.

Comment: Your question is VERY unclear. JSON is a serialization format. You can convert an "object graph" (an outer `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`) containing other container objects or data objects like strings and numeric values back and forth to JSON `NSData` using `NSJSONSerialization`. It's well documented. What are you starting with? A string? NSData? It looks to me like you are starting with an NSObject and want to convert it to JSON. The first line of your code does exactly that.

Comment: @DuncanC sorry for being unclear. 
I retrieve an array from database and NSLog it which comes as `(
        {
        "men_clothing" =         {
            Tops = Activewear;
        };
    }
)`

Comment: You need to define your problem clearly. "I am starting with an NSArray. I want to convert it to JSON. Here is the data I am starting from <data>. Here is the code I am using. I am getting the following error. Please help me solve it." Edit your question to be clear and we can reopen it.

Comment: @DuncanC sorry for that, new to this. I updated the post.

Comment: You do not "format" JSON. You can take a JSON object stored in NSData, and create an array or dictionary from it. Or you can take an array or dictionary, and convert it to a JSON object stored in NSData. At no time is there any "formatting".

Comment: @gnasher729 How would I go about converting NSData to an NSArray in JSON?

Comment: Your code already converts your objects into JSON. The cocoa object that converts objects to JSON outputs NSData. If you want to display the resulting data you need to convert the NSData to a string using `[NSString initWithData:encoding:]`. (The second line of your code, which turns the JSON data back to objects makes no sense.)

Comment: The sample data you show is a dictionary, not an array. You are very confused.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the NSArray to JSON and log that JSON:

```
NSArray * test = @[
    @"Test1", @"Test2", @"Test3"
];
NSData * testJSONData = [NSJSONSerialization
    dataWithJSONObject:test options:0 error:NULL
];
NSString * testJSONString = [[NSString alloc]
    initWithData:testJSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
];
NSLog(@"Array is:\n%@", testJSONString);
```

Output:

```
Array is:
["Test1","Test2","Test3"]
```

And if you don't use ARC, don't forget to clean up:

```
[testJSONString release];
```

Comment: I'm getting it back as `[{"men_clothing":{"Tops":"Activewear"}}]` with the `[ ]`

Comment: also I need to get it returned as an NSArray, could i do that?

Comment: You say you need to convert to JSON, then you say you need it as an NSArray. That makes no sense. If it's JSON, it's not an NSArray, and if it's an NSArray, it's not JSON. JSON is a way to converting objects into a byte stream that you can send over a serial connection or over the internet.